# Remote Mysql Database Access error when adding wildcard IP like 192.168.1.%

Tags: mysql, database, ip, ip-address, cpanel

I am trying to whitelist my IP address in MySQL database remote connection in cPanel

Remote Mysql Database Access gives error when I try to add an IP with wildcard like `192.168.1.%`

Error: `Error: 182.64.171.% is not a valid remote host`

All other exact IP like: `123.123.123.123` do not give error.

I want to add wildcard for last 2 range. Like `182.64.%.%` because my ISP changes last 2 range.

Please see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the wildcard and adding a subnet description like:

```
182.64.171.0/255.255.255.0
```

This will allow access from the whole class C subnet.

Comment: What should I do to add 182.64.%.% because my ISP changes IP address for last 2 range.

Comment: If you want to include the full class B network then you should change the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 .

Comment: So, would it be: 182.64.0.0/255.255.0.0 ?

Comment: Yes, this would be equivelant to 182.64.%.% .